# ios UIImagepickerController taking multiples video and merge to a single one

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller

My app use uiimagepickerController to record several videos and I would like to merge them into a single one, just one after the other.

and I also would like to save this merged video to photo gallery.

Anyone knows how to do this? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In one of my old legacy project I have merged two videos in Objective-C. You can inspire (but there is probably better and smarter way). My solution was:

```
+ (void) mergeVideos:(NSString*) firstVideo withVideo:(NSString*) secondVideo
{
AVMutableComposition* composition = [AVMutableComposition composition];
AVURLAsset* video1 = [[AVURLAsset alloc]initWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:firstVideo] options:nil];
AVURLAsset* video2 = [[AVURLAsset alloc]initWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:secondVideo] options:nil];
AVMutableCompositionTrack * composedTrack = [composition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];

[composedTrack insertTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, video1.duration)
                       ofTrack:[[video1 tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] objectAtIndex:0]
                        atTime:kCMTimeZero
                         error:nil];

[composedTrack insertTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, video2.duration)
                       ofTrack:[[video2 tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] objectAtIndex:0]
                        atTime:video1.duration
                         error:nil];

NSString *finalPath = [folderPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/final.mov"];
NSURL *lastURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:finalPath];
AVAssetExportSession *exporter = [[AVAssetExportSession alloc] initWithAsset:composition presetName:AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality];

exporter.outputURL=lastURL;
exporter.outputFileType = AVFileTypeMPEG4;
exporter.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = NO;
[exporter exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:^{

    switch ([exporter status]) {

        case AVAssetExportSessionStatusFailed:
            NSLog(@"failed");
            break;

        case AVAssetExportSessionStatusCancelled:
            NSLog(@"cancelled");
            break;

        case AVAssetExportSessionStatusCompleted:
            NSLog(@"fjuhuuuuu");
            break;

        default:

            break;

    }

}];
}
```

TLDR - You should look for AVMutableComposition and AVAssetExportSession in AVFoundation framework.